TV series where a large space ship has to eject their reactor before it explodes
I'm looking for an old TV show/series. This is what I recall, I saw it around 6 years ago, watching it on a VCR tape, and since then it has been thrown out.
This is what I recall of the show:
Some large space ship is having some kind of dilemma. A rescue team is called to remove their unstable reactor from the ship, and they work to cut the reactor/engine out of the ship as ominous music plays in the background. They launch it into the distance with a few rockets and it explodes far out.
I have been looking for this for over a year now, any help would be appreciated. I also think I recall it was a show made in the UK. The episode was part of a compilation of episodes (perhaps a special edition?) in the VCR tape.
Ruled out possibilities:
Captain Scarlet - Debunked a while ago

Just had a look at Space Cowboys... Unfortunately not the right thing. I believe the TV series I'm after is a bit older than Space Cowboys, perhaps in the 90s?

Just about every TV series with a large spaceship in it.

Star Trek?
Star Trek: Voyager has many occurrences of this, including Renaissance man and Day of Honour. I'm sure it occurs many times in the other Star Trek series as well.
Stargate?
The Prometheus's Naquadria reactor core was ejected into space in the Stargate SG-1 Season 6 episode, "Memento".

I was thinking the same thing! Only problem is Star Trek isn't British...

I just checked all of these. None of them match unfortunately. Good news though, I remembered a few more things about it. They actually do have to work on the outside of the ship to cut the reactor core out (with what looked like an oxy-acetylene torch), and I also remember a confrontation with an alien or something on the bridge of the ship... I also think the alien was evil and the ship was also carrying a lot of people. And just because I played this in the UK (I found it on a VCR cassete tape), dosen't neccesarily mean it's a UK show.

What about Silent Running? It has a large space ship, a rescue team and ejecting some elements of the ship that then detonate. My only concern is 1972 might be too early for the time frame you mentioned. 

Yeah, unfortunately I don't think it was this either... Thanks anyway mate.
